# How to avoid jerk/lag/struck while switching between fragments while loading images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Here is the piece of code that i'm using to load a folder of images into my app from the device memorycard.

In this code, i'm getting the image path using **file** object and passing that object to **adapter** where i'm setting the images.

```
File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Pictures" + File.separator + "test");
    final File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File _file : files) {
        myAdapter.add(_file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

But i found there is **jerk** while i'm **opening** this particular fragment. Because it is taking time to **load all images at a time** and displaying them, and found same **jerk while scrolling the page**.

Here is my **adapter class** look likes,

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


public Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public void add(String path) {
    itemList.add(path);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180dp,180dp);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(EIGHT, EIGHT, EIGHT, EIGHT);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 180dp,180dp);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);



    return imageView;
}


public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bm;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: can you show how the adapter is implemented?

Comment: decoding the bitmap by yourself is very nice but you should not do it in the UI thread, use a library like Picasso or Glide, or if you really want to do it yourself do it in another thread, decoding the bitmap is expensive and cause lag

Comment: Thank you Mr.lelloman, i'm using **Glide** for loading the **images**, you saved my day. Wish i could mark as your answer as exact output.

Comment: you are loading images on the UI thread which will cause delay for sure.
Use an Asynctask or Picasso or something and make sure to cache the already decoded images so that you dont have to decode images each time

Comment: you're welcome i just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decoding the bitmap by yourself is very nice but you should not do it in the UI thread, use a library like Picasso or Glide, or if you really want to do it yourself do it in another thread, decoding the bitmap is expensive and cause lag

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso or background threads to load images.
Furthermore, with Picasso you can set placeholders while image is loading, alternative image in case of error, fit images, etc. The result will be pretty much professional.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) FindViewById(...);

Picasso.with(getActivity())
    .load(new File("path-to-file/file.png"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .fit()
    .into(imageView);
```